# Recursively remove desktop.ini files

Tags: powershell, cmd, delete-file

I'm trying to delete all of the `desktop.ini` files in a given directory; namely `Documents\Gio`. I've tried `del /S desktop.ini` and `del /S *.ini` in cmd (admin mode) and `get-childitem .\ -include desktop.ini -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}` and `get-childitem .\ -include *.ini -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}` in PowerShell (also admin). Neither have worked. What should I do?

The `desktop.ini` files contain the following:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=This folder is shared online.
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
IconIndex=12
```

I move the directory from my Google Drive folder but all the folders still have the shared icons on them. I was trying to change the directory and all it subdirectories and files' ownership to a different account. I tried to do this with Google Drive but only the root directory changed ownership; I can't delete any of the files or directories therein.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, it acts like it works but the files are still there.

Answer (score 7):

```
del /s /a desktop.ini
```

See `del /?` for help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and here is my solution:

```
Get-Location | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Filter "desktop.ini" | Remove-Item
```

The first part gets the current active directory.

```
Get-Location
```

You could replace it with a path like:

```
"C:\Users\Chris" | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Filter "desktop.ini" | Remove-Item
```

The second part gets child items in the path.

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Filter "desktop.ini"
```

- -Force -> force seeing all child items even hidden ones, most "desktop.ini" are hidden
- -Recurse -> to be recursive
- -File -> to get only files else it could find a folder named "desktop.ini"
- -Filter "desktop.ini" -> to only get items named "desktop.ini"

The last part removes the item.

```
Remove-Item
```

Adding a -WhatIf for the first run may be safer.

```
Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Comment: why do you need to `get-location`?

Comment: @Ooker You actually don't need it as Get-ChildItem defaults to the current active directory.
`Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Filter "desktop.ini" | Remove-Item` should work too.

Comment: so why did you use it?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for Windows 2012 server

**Create Desktop.ini files**

My desktop.ini files were created from running this script which sets default folder options

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Set-ItemProperty $key Hidden 1
Set-ItemProperty $key HideFileExt 0
Set-ItemProperty $key ShowSuperHidden 1
Stop-Process -processname explorer
```

**Remove Desktop.ini files**

```
# Remove from your user desktop
gci "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -filter desktop.ini -force | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname -force}

# Remove from default desktop
gci "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" -filter desktop.ini -force | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname -force}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will grab every folder in your home directory, and then search that folder for desktop.ini and delete it.  It should be faster than using -recurse because it won't search subfolders.  It should finish neatly with no errors

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -path \\server\homedrivedirectory) {
Get-ChildItem $file.FullName -Filter desktop.ini -force | remove-item -force -WhatIf
}
```

This will grab every folder in your home directory, and then create a path for every folder to \server\homedrivedirectory\user\desktop.ini and then delete that file.  It should run a little faster as it doesn't have to search each user folder but it will turn up errors for every user folder that doesn't have a desktop.ini

```
foreach ($_ in Get-ChildItem -path \\server\homedrivedirectory) {
$path = $_.fullname
Remove-Item "$path\desktop.ini" -Force -WhatIf
}
```

I've left a -whatif so you can see what it would do in your environment without it doing it.  If you want it to actually delete the files remove the -whatif

Answer (score 0):

With powershell, you use the  [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (alias `gci`) cmdlet to retrieve all desktop.ini files and pipe it to [Remove-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373) (alias `rm`):

```
gci 'C:\YOURPATHTODOCUMENTS\GO' -Filter desktop.ini  -Recurse | rm
```

Comment: It didn't work. It acted like it did but the files are still there.